# Android Studio recognizes physical Device as Null?

Tags: android-studio, adb

I've been developing an `Android Application for Android` (SDK min version 14) and I have testing it normally with tablets such as `Samsung Galaxy 2 and Nexus 7`.
However when I tried to run the application (by clicking run in `AndroidStudio`), AS does not recognise the tablet information, which is shown in the picture below.

[image: Device is Null]

The interesting thing is that as shown in the picture above, AS is also detecting the device sdk as `API 1` when it's Android version is `4.2.2`
The tablet is already set to accept "`USB debugging`" in the developer options, I'have tried rebooting the tablet, and restarting AS, but still I get the same problem(everything is fine with `nexus 7 and Samsung Galaxy 2`).

The tablet/device I'm working on is a "VeryKool" T742

```
Environment information:
 OS: ubuntu
 AndroidStudio version: 0.8.6

 Tablet Android version:4.2.2
 Tablet Kernel version: 3.4.5
 App min SDK: 14
```

Comment: I had this issue before. It's just that the tablet isn't recognised as such by your pc and therefore don't give your user the permission to use it. You could start the adb service as root (on your pc), or simply add this device type somewhere in your udev rouls. Then it should work without the camera trick. If you change in camera mode, your device simply introduces himself with another device/product id, one known by your system.

Comment: @user3387542 but how to add this device type to my udev ?

Comment: wow. thank u so much.  I've wasted hours on it. and the final solution for me is to start android studio as the /root user. as i am using centos OS

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Ok So I finally found the problem, apparently on this device you have to set to connect as camera(even after usb debugging is already enabled)

[image]

Also [this link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Android_Studio_Apps_on_a_Physical_Android_Device) describes the setting up process

Comment: I've been looking up for days about this problem & the solution is to connect it as "Camera", this is so weird but working! thanks for sharing

Comment: in my case it was MTP selected and I had to toggle to PTP and then back to MTP for it to work.

Comment: worked on mine too! don't know what's the reason though!

Comment: In my case I also had to run this command on terminal `adb devices`

Answer (score 58):

I've seen this error a few times when adb hasn't been connected with correct permissions.

On the terminal try

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools> ./adb devices
```

if it returns

```
<deviceIdentifier> no permissions
```

then you need to restart adb with correct perms

```
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$> ./adb kill-server
~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$> sudo ./adb devices
```

if that worked then you'll get

```
List of devices attached
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
<deviceIdentifier>  device
```

No more Sdk version resolution issues in Android Studio after that.

Comment: By doing this I get to see my device name(without null) just for a sec.It is again showing null

Comment: This is the most correct answer, because Google Pixel device is null even after connection type change.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

Just run this command after you connect your device to your Ubuntu system:

```
adb devices
```

This works for me.

Note: Make sure you have selected file transfer option in your phone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598874/9022007
try this too if adb devices does not work for you

Comment: its working for me. 1) adb devices 2)Settings -> Connected Devices -> USB --> Change to 'Transferring Files'

Answer (score 17):

On Ubuntu, with my Pixel XL on 8.0, I had to do this while plugged into computer:

Settings -> Connected Devices -> USB --> Change to 'Transferring Files'

Comment: settings of what?

Comment: Phone's settings

Comment: I found my Pixel was switching to null after a while of being connected. I kept restarting the device but the same thing would happen. This sometimes fixes it but only temporarily, weird...

Comment: its working for me. 
1) adb devices 2)Settings -> Connected Devices -> USB --> Change to 'Transferring Files'

Comment: This still works in 2019 on pixel 3.
(I came here to looking for a permanent solution but still not found, this action still works)

Answer (score 12):

*Have the same problem with my Nexus 5/5X/Pixel 2 XL on Ubuntu 18.04.*

A **permanent solution** is to add a udev rule so that you can always access the device.

- Find your device with the command `lsusb`. This outputs e.g. for my Pixel 2 XL this:

  ```
  Bus 001 Device 003: ID 18d1:4ee7 Google Inc.

  # This means: BUS=001, DEVICE=003, VENDOR=18d1, PRODUCT=4ee7
  ```
- Now check the permissions. Replace 001 and 003 with your parameters:

  ```
  ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/008

  # Output: crw-rw-r-T 1 root root 189, 8 Nov 10 18:34 /dev/bus/usb/001/003
  # Unless you are root, you are missing the permissions to access the device
  ```
- To fix this, create a udev rule file with `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` with the following content:

  ```
  SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee7", MODE="0660", 
  GROUP="plugdev", SYMLINK+="android%n"

  # You need to replace "18d1" and "4ee7" with your output of `lsusb` above
  ```
- Unplug and plug you device back in. It should now always be recognized.
   *If not, restart the adb server a last time with `adb kill-server`.*

*Source: http://www.janosgyerik.com/adding-udev-rules-for-usb-debugging-android-devices/*

Answer (score 6):

Ran into the same problem while using Android Studio on Ubuntu. Apparently for me the fix was to set the USB connection mode for the device as [MTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emypw.png).

Answer (score 6):

First check adb version:If it gives Output like

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32
```

Then just restart the daemon.

```
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

else install adb first and restart the daemon
Worked for me, in ubuntu 16.04.3

Answer (score 5):

Recently, I was facing the same issue for Vivo and MI phones. I have tried everything described in this thread. 
I tried connecting as MTP, PTP; But nothing worked.

After many retries I found a solution for my case and may be it can help others too.

1. Open terminal window in Android Studio
2. Kill ADB server using following command: `adb kill-server`
3. Restart ADB server using following command: `adb start-server`

It solved my issue.

Comment: thanks saved my day.. it always shows 24213213[null] but after your manipulation its now shows Samsung Galaxy ...

Answer (score 4):

Disabling and re-enabling debugging while the device was connected did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by opening my Android device Settings, then selecting "Turn off" then "Turn on" for USB Debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I resolved this by doing

1. Android -> SDk -> platform tool

2.Open terminal for(ubuntu user) or open cmd(window user)

3.type command "sudo adb kill-server"

4.Go to android studio,then reconnect the device.

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu installing adb worked for me, I think there was some problem with default android studio one .

In terminal use command

```
sudo apt install adb
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in Linux (Centos 6 in my case) the reason can be that you didn't started Android Studio as the root user. please restart android studio as the root user and try it!

Comment: This is terrible idea. Never start userland application as root!

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu machine select the transfer option and device will detected in android studio as well as for debugging. Generally device is at charging state for windows but for ubuntu this is how it works.

Also many a times device is not detected , do the same thing again.

Answer (score 0):

Needed MTP mode, but it does not come up under the USB side. In the storage setting on the menu bar item you get to set the PC connection type as ... MTP.

Answer (score 0):

check processes running, i had several adb processes running and i think this was screwing things up for me. Kill them all then restart Studio. HTC Sync Manager, GenyMotion etc and possibly when you have multiple Android Studio windows open can result in multiple conflicting adb processes.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu especially or any other platform. Please and Please Check your adb version. I can't stress this enough. ensure it is updated or the lastest version especially if the above answers doesn't work and [this link](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/354-ubuntu-xenial-android-adb-fastboot-qtadb) also does not work.

After I updated my platform-tools folder located at

`PATH_TO/Android/Sdk/platform-tools`

which also contains the `adb` it worked.
I ran
`adb devices`

first it would show unauthorized then

you unplug and re-plug the android device.
Then your phone would ask for permission before the system would read your device.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, simply looking at my phone and ticking the pop-up checkbox to allow USB debugging did the job for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to terminal in android studio and run "adb devices". It will show the connected devices. Then Run the app and the device should show up.