# Android Studio does not detect my mobile

Tags: android

I have installed `Android Studio 1.2.1.1` on `Linux Mint 17.1 32 bits`, have setup the "Hello world" application. Connected my mobile `Lava Xolo Q800 X`. When I try to run the application, in *Choose Device* dialog box the running device list shows like `????????? null]` for device name.

In Android developer website it is said to create `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` file with the related vendor Id. There is no vendor Id for Lava in the web page and also I'm not able to find from Google.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Android Studio recognizes physical Device as Null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614067/android-studio-recognizes-physical-device-as-null).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `lsusb` command in a terminal, you will find the corresponding `idVendor` for you device (in bold here):

> Bus 002 Device 026: ID **04e8**:6860 Samsung Electronics Co. […]

Then add a rule to your `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` like this (replace `04e8` with your `idVendor`):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the device driver for your phone? This is nessesary to do for most of the Android devices, before you can find them in Android Studio. You find the device drivers on the vendors website. The only exceptions to this is the clean Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

Install the drivers. If you cant find the cd in the box download the driver from the site.

Comment: device driver for Xolo is only available for Windows as it is said here http://androidxda.com/download-xolo-usb-drivers

Comment: Try searching for xolo only. Ignore the lava!