# Android error No, minSdk(API 19) > deviceSdk(API 1)

Tags: android, gradle

I have just set up android studio and am trying to compile my first project. The project gets compiled but when the 'Choose Device' menu opens the device and state is shown as [OFFLINE] and compatible gives message Android error message Android error 
'`No, minSdk(API 19) > deviceSdk(API 1)`'
 What does this mean? How can I solve it?

my build.grandle file looks like this

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yaron.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Which device are you using? What version of Android is it running?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are a few things to check.

if you go to the terminal window in Android Studio and cd to the path where your sdk platform tools are installed (something like C:\Android\SDK\platform-tools ) and run the following command

`adb devices`

Do you have a device listed? If not then you don't have the device setup properly, or the correct drivers.

On the phone make sure that you have developer options enabled (go to settings->about phone and click on the Build Number 7 times or so)

Once you have enabled that go into the develop options under settings and make sure  USB debugging is enabled.

If `adb devices` said "no permission" for the device you are connecting, make sure to connect it as MTP device first. This will implicitly prompt you to import the computer's fingerprint and allow future connections for USB debugging as well.

Comment: if you have this option already checked, uncheck and then check again while device is conected to your PC

Comment: Do adb devices first. That was my fix. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210152/set-up-device-for-development-no-permissions

Comment: Please add @Jordi's answer below to this answer.`adb devices` listed the device but said "no permission" for me, thus Android Studio could not tell the API version and assumed 1 (see original question!). Connecting as MTP implicitly solved the issue. Admittedly, many people will have done that before, but if you are debugging with many devices, it may well be that you have not done it before.

Answer (score 10):

In build.gradle file, change the minSdkVersion to 7

Answer (score 8):

ADB Secure device authorizations are stored in a white-list located in the adb directory. if you want to connect to the ADB daemon running on the android device from a process running on the device via tcp as localhost then the connection is successful but the Authorisation prompt is not displayed and the device is shown as Offline.

You need to have root access in order to remove RSA keys from the white-list.
When the pop up "Allow USB Debugging" comes on the phone screen, press "Ok" to enable it. if not unplug and re-plug to see the prompt.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Same problem with a tablet with Android 4.4.2, in my case solved enabling MTP:

> Settings-> Storage-> Three dots on top right->USB computer
>   connection->Emable "Media device (MTP)"

Of course, debugging was already enabled.

Comment: I can confirm it for android 5.1.1 and sony z3 compact, MTP mode helps in this situation.

Comment: For me it was exactly the opposite. I had to set the tablet to FTP, instead of MTP. Strange :S

Answer (score 4):

Following steps solved my problem

Step 1: Open your Android Studio, and go to Menu. **File >Project Structure**

Step 2: In project Structure window, select **app** module in the list given on left side.

Step 3: Select the **Flavors** tab and under this you will have an option for setting “**Min Sdk Version**” and for setting “**Target Sdk Version**”.

Step 4: Select both the versions and Click **OK**.

Excerpt from http://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/change-api-sdk-level-android-studio.html

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Got same error 'Compatible No, minSdk(API 19) > deviceSdk(API 1)' in Android Studio Device Chooser for Samsung Tablet with Android 4.4.2. The below simple steps resolved the issue for me:

1. Disconnect the USB debug cable
2. Open Developer Options in Settings on the device
3. Click Revoke USB debugging authorizations
4. Click OK to 'USB debugging access will be revoked from all the computers you have previously authorized'
5. Reconnect over USB and accept the new 'Allow USB debugging' authorization for this computer
6. Start a new debugging session

Answer (score 2):

This most likely means that you have not allowed USB debugging. When you connect your device to your computer, your device should prompt you to "Allow USB debugging?" Just hit OK to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with build tools version that you are using.

Please try the following:

Android Studio=>Open your project=>File=>Project Structure=>app(i.e left pannel)=>Properties=>Build Tools Version=>

Select 19.1.0.

It worked fine for me..Just try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

the storage space of my smartphone was full. After cleaning up I was able to use it and the device was "compatible".

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @NeilMasson if the storage is full the device is unable to have the app loaded onto it. It's unable to do a lot of functions.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `minSdkVersion` to your target device `sdkVersion` in `build.gradle(Module:app)` file will be appear on left side in Gradle Scripts.

Ex: 
 `minSdkVersion 24`

Change the version value to your target device value (23, 22, 21 or other)

According to your configuration you have to change the `minSdkVersion 19` to `minSdkVersion 1`, because your target device is at API Level 1.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on a VirtualBox Linux (Ubuntu 15.10 guest on a 14.04 host). `adb devices` showed `unauthorized`.

In this case, this was fixed by adding a `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules` with the proper rule on the guest and clearing all previous authorizations under developer options on the Android device. (Was set previously to the same computer as the device was rooted for CyanogenMod.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set to connect as camera(even after usb debugging is already enabled)

[image]

Answer taken from [Android Studio recognizes physical Device as Null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614067/android-studio-recognizes-physical-device-as-null)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. My resolution in Android Studio was to set check on:
Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration

Answer (score 0):

Unplug and re-plug to see if the prompt appears and click on allow. Of course, USB debugging must be enabled from developer options. And the mobile's driver must be installed on the pc (if on windows).

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away when I disabled and re-enabled USB debugging in my Android device's Developer Options settings.

Answer (score 0):

In the bundle.gradle(Module: app) change  *minSdkVersion 19*  from **19** to **1**. This fixed my probem

Answer (score 0):

****I resolve my this error by installing new android device with API 19 and than runs fine...**..**

Answer (score 0):

On your file `build.gradle` you need to add  the correct API of your **deviceSdk**.

**minSdkVersion 1**

minSdk(API 19) > deviceSdk(API 1)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkEYY.png

i am using USB and my Connected Device

Answer (score 0):

Goto your Project's Gradle Script >> build.gradle (Module: app)
Change **minSdkVersion** as show below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rehman.doctorportal"
```

> minSdkVersion 17
>
> Change it to two numbers small of your error's number

```
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}