# Android device not recognized by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have 2 android devices. One is samsung tablet and the other one is general mobile discovery phone. Android studio recognizes samsung tablet when i choose debug mode and I successfully run my simple applications on the tablet. However the studio doesnt recognize my phone. Im using Win7 and my pc recognizes the phone to copy files from/to. Can you suggest any solution?

Comment: is debugging enables in the phone? if yes then reinstall the drives of your phone, it will most probably solve the problem

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16707217/4565322

Comment: what about adb? does it show up on `adb devices`?

Comment: @bigdestroyer : It was easy to find for samsung tablet,but I couldnt find for this phone.

Comment: @rupps : No, not any device on adb.

Answer (score 1):

Sure that you have installed in your TOOLS:

[image]

Comment: Have installed the sdk of the mobile phone that no recognized?

Comment: What do you mean by sdk of the mobile phone?

Comment: check the version of Android you have installed on your phone and see if you have this version installed on your pc . For example if you have version 5, the API should have installed 21

Comment: I have 4.2.1 on phone.On pc : android sdk tools 24.4.1,android sdk paltform tools 23.1

Comment: I just remembered that it works for me: [link](http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to an answer I submitted before.

[Android error No, minSdk(API 19) > deviceSdk(API 1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633271/android-error-no-minsdkapi-19-devicesdkapi-1/30633585#30633585)

There are a few things to check.

if you go to the terminal window in Android Studio and cd to the path where your sdk platform tools are installed (something like C:\Android\SDK\platform-tools ) and run the following command

adb devices

Do you have a device listed? If not then you don't have the device setup properly, or the correct drivers.

On the phone make sure that you have developer options enabled (go to settings->about phone and click on the Build Number 7 times or so)

Once you have enabled that go into the develop options under settings and make sure USB debugging is enabled.

Comment: I wrote adb devices and the result is : "list of devices attached" (but no device shown.) Also did clicked 7 times and it said now you are a developer.But still no device. Enabled/disabled debugging several times.

Comment: have you setup the device as a developer device by tapping the build number?  Do you have USB debugging enabled?

Comment: You are on windows If you go to Administrative Tools->Computer Management and select Device Manager, do you have any warning icons, or do you see anything as an ADB Interface?

Comment: Yes,tapped 7 times(now you are a developer) and usb debugging enabled. I checked device manager but no warning. The phone is shown on the list under portable devices but with no special name,just as "H:\"

Comment: Is there an icon at the top that allows you to change the USB debugging mode?  Some phones allow to change between media device or camera etc.  Sometimes that helps.

Comment: Yes I tried that trick many times (switching usb storage option on-off,debugging mode on-off several times) but it didnt work for me.

Comment: Also look at what PurpleSoft noted above and make sure that the Google USB driver was installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Mac or Windows` then try [PdaNet](http://pdanet.co/), this tool works with most devices and really useful if you are using devices by regional or country based manufacturers.

Comment: Any reasons for downvoting this one? Did you try this?

Comment: Its not me, I tried pdaneta4126 but didnt work for me.

Comment: Can you please tell which device you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your PC not install the driver for the mobile device. Try download **UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi** from  http://hexamob.com/news/download-android-usb-drivers-for-onda/