# Possible Problems when upgrading the minSdkVersion

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk

I'm currently working on a project where I am programming a part of an app (as in: a lot of the App was already programmed by other people)
I want to implement a Library which needs a minSdkVersion of 25, but the app is currently on 22.
What possible Problems could there be? (Apart from users not being able to use the app if their SDK is too low)

I'm very sorry if this question doesn't belong here, this is my first post and I don't know if it is code related enough :)

I've asked my boss and he said that it's difficult because you need to be careful with other libraries that won't work anymore, which doesn't make sense to me because if you're upgrading the minSdkVersion there shouldn't be any problems because the libraries have to be compatible with everything upwards of 22 (that's what I think)

I have asked him already, but I'm not sure that his explanation makes sense to me, so I wanted to ask if anyone knows anything more specific for this/can explain why the libraries could be a problem (or point me to the right direction of researching it, cause I can't find any sources)

Comment: Some possible scenarios include incompatibility, lack of features, crashes, and bugs. However, if the code was built in a way that makes it easier to use in the future, by some miracle, it might function as expected.

Comment: @ApaxPhoenix it actually does work when I do it, but can you point me to any sources why this shouldn't be the case?

Comment: Here are some sources, that you might want to check out: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/893, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4458934270994-minSdkVersion-16-cannot-be-smaller-than-version-19-declared-in-library, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633271/android-error-no-minsdkapi-19-devicesdkapi-1

Answer (score 0):

I think when you upgrade the minimum SDK version, it won't affect other libraries or your app functionaly. However, you should be aware that if you want to upgrade the minimum SDK version, it will also change the minimum Android version required to run your application. You can read the details [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platforms?hl=id#7.1)!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew that it will change the minimum android version required to run the app, I am searching for sources if the libraries will be affected or not :)