# Android Studio, No, minSdk(API 14) > deviceSdk(API 1), moto G, Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-15.04, android-min-sdk

I just installed Android Studio (v1.4) on Ubuntu 15.04 (64) and am unable to connect to my Moto G (Android 5.0.2) to run the application I made from a tutorial.

When asked to choose a device, I get the following choice for my device:
TA9290IPXK [NULL]         No, minSdk(API 14)>deviceSdk(API 1)   TA9290IPXK

I already enabled USB debugging on the device. when running 'adb devices' I get " ?????????????? no permission " and after killing and restarting the adv server it displays the proper serial ID but when going back to Android Studio it still does not work.

Has anyone encountered this issue ? Can someone provide a suggestion of solution please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution

Turns out I had 2 ADB installed in different Paths and Android studio was getting one of them that was not the correctly configured. I also had not properly set up the udev rules.

Here are the step I took to get it fixed
1. Remove ADB that was installed manually
2. Modify the udev rules to add the devices (It turns out that both my Nexus 7 and Moto G were not Asus and Motorolla respectively but Google inc instead. I acquired the right Vendor ID code using "lsusb" It returns XXXX:YYYY the vendir iD is the XXXX
3. Add the location of the right adb to path ( /Sdk/platform-tools/)
4. Then rebooted all of the devices (computer and android devices) and it seems it worked.

Sorry for not giving out all the terminal lines that were entered, being novice with Ubuntu it may have been a lot more confusing than helping.

Hopefully it can help someone that is in the same situation.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious reason for that error message “No, minSDK(API 14) > deviceSDK(API 1)”, which I didn´t find so far mentioned neither at StackOverflow nor by other forums:

If the AVD Manager option for a virtual device “Emulated Performance - [ ] Use Host GPU” is unchecked, the Android simulator works just on "API 1" level :-(.

So if you try to execute a standard Android app ( e.g. "API 14" level ) with this setting,

1. The Android desktop screen is not displayed but just black screen with “android” in white letters.
2. When executing “Run / Device Chooser / Choose a running device / Compatible” again, there is the error message “No, minSDK(API 14) > deviceSDK(API 1)”, if “minSDKVersion 14” is set in the project configuration file “app”.

-

Why should you ever try to run the Android simuator with unchecked option?

Well...If your Win8 or Linux computer really provides OpenGL2 graphics, you may operate the simulator with default setting “Emulated Performance - [x] Use Host GPU”.

But if your Win8 or Linux computer just provides OpenGL1 graphics, as my legacy Win8-32bit notebooks “ASUS Eee PC T101MT” and “Dell Vostro 1000” with standard Windows drivers by Microsoft, the Android Simulator crashes by the error message “APPCRASH”, “Fault Module name: libOpenglRender.dll”.

And so by unchecking the option, you can´t run Android apps requiring a usual API level ( API 14,... ) :-(.

Read this article about the incomplete rollout of OpenGL2 drivers for Win,Linux and MacOX on current and legacy computers :-(: 
https://github.com/processing/processing/wiki/OpenGL-Issues

Sincerely
Rolf

Answer (score 2):

You have to set to connect as camera(even after usb debugging is already enabled)

[image]

Thanks to [@Jorch914](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614067/android-studio-recognizes-physical-device-as-null)

Answer (score 1):

i already found the solution to this. in order to solve this one, is go to Gradle > Build.gradle(module:app) > and then change the minSdkVersion that is compatible with your phone. Hope this help! :)