# SDK version issue: it should be higher than API 1

Tags: android, sdk

I'm trying to make some practices with Android Studio, so I created a project for the 4.4 (KitKat) version. Now I'm trying to use it in my phone (Samsung Galaxy S5), tried to get automatically the latest drivers and so, and could see it on the "Select Deployment Target" screen.

But something is wrong: it states that: minimumSDK(API 19) > deviceSDK(API 1).

I guess that something is going wrong here, since I have Android 5.0 Lollipop.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633271/android-error-no-minsdkapi-19-devicesdkapi-1) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33028430/android-studio-no-minsdkapi-14-devicesdkapi-1-moto-g-ubuntu-15-04). Similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a custom rom, it may be caused by an invalid SDK mentionned in the `build.prop` of your device.
Try to edit it maybe ?