# Debug on android studio gives "incompatible, minSdk > deviceSdk"

Tags: android, android-studio

I just plugged my phone to try to debug my projects on it because de VM wasn't working. When I click "run app" is shows "The selected device is incompatible"

Up on the menu says "Compatible: No, minSdk(API 15) > deviceSdk(API 1)"

EDIT:
I found this on the internet which describes exactly the error I'm having but I think the solution is not suitable (also, I tried it and didn't worked)

http://code2care.org/2015/the-selected-device-is-incompatible-android-studio/

There it says to set my minSdkVersion to the lower version of the cellphone I'm trying to run. Isn't there a better way to solve it? Can't "update" my phone's API to it's current? 
Also, why it accuses me of being on API 1 if I'm using android 5.1?

Comment: what menu? What Android version? what is specified in the gradle build settings? AndroidManifest.xml? deviceSdk(1) .. either that or your vm needs to be resetted.

Comment: the menu is that Chooser Dialog. My phone is android 5.1. On the build gradle I got 
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
            minifyEnabled false
what is to check on manifest? didn't understand.
I'm very noob at this btw

Also, what does the vm has to do about it? I thought that it was only to emulate the program, since I'm trying to run it directly on my phone, so why would I need to reset vm?

Comment: **Found a simple solution in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25628891/2414842)**