# Android Studio can't choose s6 edge as running device, sdk is too low

Tags: android, sdk, device

I'm trying to use my S6 Edge to run a "Hello World" app with Android Studio, but when I try to select the S6 it says under compatibility: "No, minSdk(API 8) > deviceSdk(API 1). Should my S6 edge have such a low API and if so how do I update it?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614067/android-studio-recognizes-physical-device-as-null

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't work. Still says that my android SDK is only 1??

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu,
I think you have a problem about device permissions.

Try

```
sudo su
sudo adb kill-server
sudo adb start-server
```

In my case it solved my problem