# Android studio showing device as someAlphanumeric[null]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

I am using Redmi Note 5 Pro as a physical device to connect to the android studio. A night before everything was working fine and I was able to install apps from android studio to my physical device and view Logs with ease but Now apparently it's not working and showing the device as NULL. Please help.
I tried the [post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614067/android-studio-recognizes-physical-device-as-null) but it is not working for me.

PS: The only thing I did was update a system update MIUI 9.5.14.0 in between but I suppose that should not be the reason for this.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: There are a number of solutions in the link, which ones did you try?

Comment: you told that you have updated your MIUI so may be your device will support higher api version, try to upgrade your project api level and run it again.

Comment: @MorrisonChang all with upvotes >=2

Comment: @HemantParmar if the device is showing NULL while clicking the run button and in the logcat window as well. How will changing the api level make it work? I guess that's something runtime dependent.right?

Comment: well i am not much sure about it, but try this atleast once. what target version you set in project??

Comment: @Falcon do you have another PC to check with using a updated `adb`?

Comment: @MorrisonChang No. Currently, I am away from my usual workplace. I only have access to my machine right now.

Comment: @HemantParmar  minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    compileSdkVersion = 26

Comment: @MorrisonChang  It worked. The solution was to kill the server. even though the device was visible in the list. I killed the adb server to start again.

Comment: @HemantParmar the issue is solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25614067/android-studio-recognizes-physical-device-as-null)

```
   ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools> ./adb devices
```

Then restart the adb despite it shows  **device** by

```
   ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$> ./adb kill-server

   ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$> sudo ./adb devices
```

This worked for me. Since it showed the device as against the answer in post prior to killing the adb server.

Answer (score 0):

A more permanent solution instead of restarting the adb service every time you can **add a udev rule so that you can always access the device.**

*See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51554826/5815054*